# Is there a limit how often a developer can push updates to TestFlight?

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect, testflight

When using TestFlight and pushing updates to a Github repository, I am wondering if there are any limits on how frequently developers can push new updates to TestFlight. Specifically, I want to automatically create a new TestFlight version every time I push updates to my repository.

Are there any limitations or restrictions that I should be aware of that might result in my app getting blocked? And is there a limit on creating a new version while a previous version is being processed by TestFlight or App Store Connect?